# Заменить в переменной определенные символы

Tags: php

Приветствую всех зашедших

```
$slovlo = "qi]owrpf}ih2834hf{984u3.hf9uehwr";
$nelza = "{}.";
```

Как можно из переменной $slovlo убрать все символы из переменной $nelza?

p.s. Конечно можно по символьно в цикле пройтись implode/explode, но при большой переменной начинает тормозить

Comment: $nelza большая бывает ? может из нее регексп просто сделать ? типа такого 
$reg="/[\{\}\.]/";
preg_replace($slovo,'',$reg);

Comment: Бывает по разному, от 5 до 40 знаков, а том числе и буквы там бывают и цифры

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$slovlo = "qi]owrpf}ih2834hf{984u3.hf9uehwr";
$nelza = "{}.";
echo preg_replace('/['.$nelza.']+/','',$slovlo); // qi]owrpfih2834hf984u3hf9uehwr
```

**UPD** с подачи [[@eicto](/users/11304/eicto)](/users/11304/eicto)

```
echo preg_replace('/['.preg_quote($nelza).']+/','',$slovlo);
```

Comment: `$nelza = '{}.\\';` 
   `$nelza = '{}.[]';`

Comment: Согласен. Заэкранировать надо. Но у вас тоже ошибочка - синтаксис слегка перепутали. Первый параметр - паттерн, а вы его последним сделали.

    mixed preg_replace ( mixed $pattern , mixed $replacement , mixed $subject [, int $limit = -1 [, int &$count ]] )

Comment: спасибо fixed this

Answer (score 2):

вот так можно `$nelza` превратить в regexp, а потом удалить символы содержащиеся в `$nelza` из `$slovo`

```
$reg='/['.preg_quote($nelza).']/';
preg_replace($reg,'',$slovo);
```

быстрее способа я не припоминаю.